# making numpy.nanargmin return nan if column is all nan

Tags: python, numpy, nan

Is it possible to use `numpy.nanargmin`, so that it returns `numpy.nan`, on columns where there are only nans in them. Right now, it raises a `ValueError`, when that happens. And i cant use `numpy.argmin`, since that will fail when there are only a few nans in the column.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmin.html says that the `ValueError` is raised for all-nan slices. In that case, i want it to return numpy.nan (just to further mask the "non-data" with nans)

this next bit does this, but is super-slow and not really pythonic:

```
for i in range(R.shape[0]):
    bestindex = numpy.nanargmin(R[i,:])
    if(numpy.isnan(bestindex)):
        bestepsilons[i]=numpy.nan
    else:
        bestepsilons[i]=epsilon[bestindex]
```

This next bit works too, but only if no all-nan columns are involved:

```
ar = numpy.nanargmin(R, axis=1)
bestepsilons = epsilon[ar]
```

So ideally i would want this last bit to work with all-nan columns as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
# makes everything nan to start with
bestepsilons1 = numpy.zeros(R.shape[0])+numpy.nan 
# finds the indices where the entire column would be nan, so the nanargmin would raise an error
d0 = numpy.nanmin(R, axis=1) 
# on the indices where we do not have a nan-column, get the right index with nanargmin, and than put the right value in those points
bestepsilons1[~numpy.isnan(d0)] = epsilon[numpy.nanargmin(R[~numpy.isnan(d0),:], axis=1)]
```

This basically is a workaround, by only taking the nanargmin on the places where it will not give an error, since at those places we want the resulting index to be a nan anyways

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> def _nanargmin(arr, axis):
...    try:
...       return np.nanargmin(arr, axis)
...    except ValueError:
...       return np.nan
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = np.array([[np.nan]*10, np.ones(10)])
>>> _nanargmin(a, axis=1)
nan
>>> _nanargmin(a, axis=0)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Anyway, it's unlikely to be what you want. Not sure what exactly you are after. If all you want is to filter away the `nan`s, then use boolean indexing:

```
>>> a[~np.isnan(a)]
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> np.argmin(_)
0
```

EDIT2: Looks like you're after the masked arrays:

```
>>> a = np.vstack(([np.nan]*10, np.arange(10), np.arange(11, 1, -1)))
>>> a[2, 4] = np.nan
>>> m = np.ma.masked_array(a, np.isnan(a))
>>> np.argmin(m, axis=0)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
>>> np.argmin(m, axis=1)
array([0, 0, 9])
```

Comment: then i get "index must be either an int or a sequence", on the line where i do bestepsilons = epsilon[ar]

Comment: Sure, you can't index an array with a `nan`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: getting the best model fit on each point, but if on a certain point, one of the parameters does not exist, all simulated values on that point will return nan as well. After that i get the best simulated value with the argmin. The idea is to do this argmin over the entire image at the same time with 'axis', but that doesnt work if there are points with bad data in them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an array of shape (nz,ny,nx) with some
slices [:,j,i] totally filled with NaNs. In my case I needed
argmax index along axis=0 and if I do

```
np.nanargmax(array,axis=0)
```

I get "ValueError: All-NaN slice encountered"

Considering that I'm not interested into argmax for slices made all of NaNs, as a workaround I filled the NaNs with zeros

```
mask = np.isnan(array)
array[mask] = 0
idx2d = np.argmax(array,axis=0)
```

This gives the indexes of max of array along axis=0. The idx2d array can be re-masked again

```
idx2d = np.ma.masked_where(mask[0],idx2d)
```

If you seek for np.argmin you can do the same steps but setting your array to a Huge number instead of 0.