# push for-loop to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Can this next for-loop be done any faster by pushing it down to numpy?

```
ri = numpy.zeros((R.shape[0],R.shape[2]))
for i in range(R.shape[0]):
    ri[i, :] = R[i, indices[i], :]
```

This relates to my previous question [making numpy.nanargmin return nan if column is all nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321995/making-numpy-nanargmin-return-nan-if-column-is-all-nan) , which was to speed up this bit:

```
bestepsilons = numpy.zeros((R.shape[0]))
for i in range(R.shape[0]):
    bestindex = numpy.nanargmin(R[i,:])
    if(numpy.isnan(bestindex)):
        bestepsilons[i]=numpy.nan
    else:
        bestepsilons[i]=epsilon[bestindex]
```

and got solved (by myself) as:

```
bestepsilons1 = numpy.zeros(R.shape[0])+numpy.nan
d0 = numpy.nanmin(R, axis=1) # places where the best index is not a nan
bestepsilons1[~numpy.isnan(d0)] = epsilon[numpy.nanargmin(R[~numpy.isnan(d0),:], axis=1)]
```

But now the more complicated case is:

```
bestepsilons = numpy.zeros((R.shape[0]))
for i in range(R.shape[0]):
    bestindex = numpy.nanargmin(R[i,indices[i],:])
    if(numpy.isnan(bestindex)):
        bestepsilons[i]=numpy.nan
    else:
        bestepsilons[i]=epsilon[bestindex]
```

And now this trick to show the places where the best index is not a nan does not work anymore with that axis argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this is faster by about 10%:

```
d1 = numpy.arange(R.shape[0])[:,None]
d2 = indices[numpy.arange(R.shape[0])][:,None]
d3 = numpy.arange(R.shape[2])[None,:]
ri = R[d1,d2,d3]

bestepsilons = numpy.zeros(R.shape[0])+numpy.nan
d0 = numpy.nanmin(ri, axis=1) # places where the best index is not a nan
bestepsilons[~numpy.isnan(d0)] = epsilon[numpy.nanargmin(ri[~numpy.isnan(d0),:], axis=1)]
```

But this is with R defined as:

```
R = (self.VVm[:,None,None]-VVs[None,:,:])**2 + (self.HHm[:,None,None]-HHs[None,:,:])**2
```

and i found that if i define R differently it speeds up a huge load more:

```
ti = indices[numpy.arange(len(VVm))]
R1 = (VVm[:,None]-VVs[ti,:])**2+(HHm[:,None]-HHs[ti,:])**2
d0 = numpy.nanmin(R1, axis=1) # places where the best index is not a nan
bestepsilons2[~numpy.isnan(d0)] = epsilon[numpy.nanargmin(R1[~numpy.isnan(d0),:], axis=1)]
```

This way it does not need to make a 3D R, but makes it directly in 2D (gets a 4X speedup)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to push it down to numpy but whether or not it is faster will depend on the sizes of your arrays. Hopefully, there is a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
ii = np.arange(R.shape[0]) * R.shape[1] + indices
ri = R.reshape(-1, R.shape[2])[ii]
```

Here are a couple timing tests:

```
def f1(R, indices):
    ri = numpy.zeros((R.shape[0],R.shape[2]))
    for i in range(R.shape[0]):
        ri[i, :] = R[i, indices[i], :]
    return ri

def f2(R, indices):
    ii = np.arange(R.shape[0]) * R.shape[1] + indices
    return R.reshape(-1, R.shape[2])[ii]
```

Smaller `R`:

```
In [25]: R = np.random.rand(30, 40, 50)
In [26]: indices = np.random.choice(range(R.shape[1]), R.shape[0], replace=True) 
In [27]: %timeit(f1(R, indices))
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.4 us per loop
In [28]: %timeit(f2(R, indices))
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.9 us per loop
```

Larger `R`:

```
In [29]: R = np.random.rand(300, 400, 500)
In [30]: indices = np.random.choice(range(R.shape[1]), R.shape[0], replace=True) 
In [31]: %timeit(f1(R, indices))
1000 loops, best of 3: 713 us per loop
In [32]: %timeit(f2(R, indices))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

In [33]: np.all(f1(R, indices) == f2(R, indices))
Out[33]: True
```